# Get polynomial trendline from multiple graphs

Tags: regression, trend

I am trying to plot a trendline from multiple datasets of an experiment. This is what my graphs look like. They may not have the same range or the same X values:

[image]

I usually go to google sheets and get a trend-line that gives me a polynomial fit and a error (R^2) value depicting how the data fits.

I am not sure what sheets uses to compute the polynomial, but I would like to do that myself programatically (I use python). One way to do it is compute the "mean" graph using interpolation and get a polynomial fit of the mean line. Is there another technique I can use that can better approximate these multiple graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code illustrating one of the ways to do this. In this code two data sets are individually fit to polynomials and a combined data set is made and fit to a third polynomial. Note several things about this approach: the "combined" fit statistics are poor, and each of the "combined" polynomial coefficients are actually the average of the corresponding coefficients of the other two fits. This shows that you can simply take the average value for each of the individual fit parameters - however if the individual data sets have different number of data points, you must use a weighted average. That is, if data set A has 30 percent of the total number of data points, data set B has 10 percent, and data set C has the remaining 60 percent, then combined parameter B0 is a weighted average calculated as B0_combined = (0.3 * B0_A) + (0.1 * B0_B) + (0.6 * B0_C).

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polynomialOrder = 2 # example quadratic

### data section
xData_A = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7, 0.0])
yData_A = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7, 0.1])

xData_B = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7, 0.0])
yData_B = numpy.array([11.0, 120.2, 130.4, 140.6, 150.8, 160.9, 170.9, 10.1])

xData_Combo = numpy.append(xData_A, xData_B)
yData_Combo = numpy.append(yData_A, yData_B)

### fitting section
fittedParameters_A = numpy.polyfit(xData_A, yData_A, polynomialOrder)
fittedParameters_B = numpy.polyfit(xData_B, yData_B, polynomialOrder)
fittedParameters_Combo = numpy.polyfit(xData_Combo, yData_Combo, polynomialOrder)

print('Fitted Parameters A:', fittedParameters_A)
print('Fitted Parameters B:', fittedParameters_B)
print('Fitted Parameters Combined:', fittedParameters_Combo)

print()

modelPredictions_A = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters_A, xData_A)
modelPredictions_B = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters_B, xData_B)
modelPredictions_Combo = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters_Combo, xData_Combo)

absError_A = modelPredictions_A - yData_A
absError_B = modelPredictions_B - yData_B
absError_Combo = modelPredictions_Combo - yData_Combo


### fit statistics section
SE_A = numpy.square(absError_A) # squared errors A
MSE_A = numpy.mean(SE_A) # mean squared errors A
RMSE_A = numpy.sqrt(MSE_A) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE A
Rsquared_A = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError_A) / numpy.var(yData_A))
print('RMSE A:', RMSE_A)
print('R-squared A:', Rsquared_A)

print()

SE_B = numpy.square(absError_B) # squared errors B
MSE_B = numpy.mean(SE_B) # mean squared errors B
RMSE_B = numpy.sqrt(MSE_B) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE B
Rsquared_B = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError_B) / numpy.var(yData_B))
print('RMSE B:', RMSE_B)
print('R-squared B', Rsquared_B)

print()

SE_Combo = numpy.square(absError_Combo) # squared errors Comb0
MSE_Combo = numpy.mean(SE_Combo) # mean squared errors Combo
RMSE_Combo = numpy.sqrt(MSE_Combo) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE Combo
Rsquared_Combo = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError_Combo) / numpy.var(yData_Combo))
print('RMSE Combo:', RMSE_Combo)
print('R-squared Combo:', Rsquared_Combo)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelsAndScatterPlots(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData_A, yData_A,  'D')
    axes.plot(xData_B, yData_B,  'D')
    # combo contains these same points, no need to replot in this example

    # create data for the fitted equation plots
    xModel_A = numpy.linspace(min(xData_A), max(xData_A))
    yModel_A = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters_A, xModel_A)

    xModel_B = numpy.linspace(min(xData_B), max(xData_B))
    yModel_B = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters_B, xModel_B)

    xModel_Combo = numpy.linspace(min(xData_Combo), max(xData_Combo))
    yModel_Combo = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters_Combo, xModel_Combo)

    # now the models as a line plots
    axes.plot(xModel_A, yModel_A)
    axes.plot(xModel_B, yModel_B)
    axes.plot(xModel_Combo, yModel_Combo)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelsAndScatterPlots(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```